# Using 'grep' and other utilities

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing, sort

I know this is a seemingly peculiar question, but I want to have a better understanding of using Linux utilities so I'm going to ask for something that seems rather complicated to me to understand the mechanisms at work better .

Considering all header files in our system, how can I display in the terminal a sorted list  of those files based on the number of defined macros in them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for file in $(find /usr/include/ -name '*.h'); do
  echo "$file,$(grep -c '#define' $file)"; done \
  | sort -n -k2 -t, -r
```

- Find list all files matching /usr/include/*.h pattern
- Print the file name, the comma and the number of lines matching '#define' pattern
- Sort numerically, using a comma as a delimiter by the second field (reverse order).

You can append `| head -10` to get the top 10 files.

Comment: This was incredibly cool, thank you a lot for not only providing a readable solution but also  a good explanation !

Comment: Happy to help! Make sure to consider switching to other scripting languages before your one-liners' sizes get out of hand :)

Comment: You can improve this: `grep -cR '^#define' /usr/include/ --include '*.h' | sort -nrt: -k2` - this is somewhat safer, protecting from spaces and such (usually one shouldn't do `for f in $(find ..)`, and certainly not without quoting `"$f"` when used.

Comment: Agreed, it was merely a quick example on a known dataset.